# how to float text in a bootstrap map

Tags: css

hello everyone I would like to float some text in the example of a boostrap card I have tried a multitude of things but without success

```
  <div class="card mb-3" style="max-width: 540px;">
  <div class="row g-0">
     <div class="col-md-8">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
        <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
        <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
      </div>
    </div>
     <div class="col-md-4">
      <img src="..." alt="...">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you clarify the result you would like? Are you floating `.card`? If so, have you tried `.float-left`? See https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/float/

Answer (score 1):

Your image already floats? With your code as is? Though I would recommend putting the row inside the card body. Or are you looking for classic float behaviour where the text uses the full line below the image?

Here's your code with my suggestions - please use full page preview.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="card mx-auto mt-4" style="max-width: 540px;">
  <div class="card-body">
    <div class="row g-0">
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
        <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
        <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ef/Stack_Overflow_icon.svg/768px-Stack_Overflow_icon.svg.png" height="100" alt="...">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello
thank you for the answer
I ended up giving up the card system and just used a float class